# How can I reference a game object on my scene in a prefab component I have just instantiated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I am learning both Unity and C#. I am working on a small game where I control a spaceship  on the screen, while meteors are spawning in a random position outside of the camera's visible space, then start to move towards the ship.

For this I am trying to refer to the ship game object in a component on a meteor prefab, to get it's position and the angle needed to start moving towards the ship.

```
public class meteorPath : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public GameObject ship;
    void Start()
    {
        int typeOf = Random.Range(2, 11);
        Vector3 posOf = new Vector3(Random.Range(-7f, 7f), Random.Range(16f, 8f), 0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(typeOf, typeOf, 1);
        transform.localPosition = posOf;
    }

    
}
```

How can I make get the player's position to calculate the angle needed every time I instantiate a meteor?

Comment: `ship.position`?

Comment: @MathewHD I have problems referencing the ship Gameobject to this script, I can not choose any object from my scene as the ship gameobject.

Comment: Is the Ship Gameobject already in your scene, then just drag it into the slot in the meteorPath script on your prefab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're instantiating everything at runtime.

You would either do:

1. GameObject.Find(********YOUR OBJECT NAME********)
2. GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(****sometag****), only if your player has a tag
3. Make player's class singleton and reference it from other classes with PlayerClassName.InstanceName and reference the position.

If you're not instantiating everything but is a static scene, then just make a prefab of the meteor with the player's reference inside

Answer (score 0):

one way to get references is to create instanced game manager:
and when meteor is created you have it get player position from that instanced GameManager.
in start of meteor:
private Vector3 playerPosition = GameManager.instance.playerPosition.transform.position;
in GameManager:

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static GameManager instance;

```
public GameObject playerPosition;

private void Awake()
{
    
   
        instance = this;
    
    
}
```